# Как обновить RecycleView?

Tags: android, alert, dialog, recycleview

В activity есть RecycleView и fab, по нажатию на fab появялется alertDialog, где ввожу в два editText данные, эти данные нужно вывести в recycleView. Как это проделать?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ItemTouchHelperListener{

private List<Notes> notesList;
private NotesHandler notesHandler;
private NotesAdapter notesAdapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private FloatingActionButton fab;
private Intent intent;

private EditText subject, text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    notesHandler = new NotesHandler(getApplicationContext());

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycle_view);

    fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

...

fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.create, null);

            builder.setView(view);
            builder.setTitle("Создать");

            subject = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_subject);
            text = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

            builder.setPositiveButton("Добавить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    writable();
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            builder.show();
        }
    });

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    prepareData();

    notesAdapter = new NotesAdapter(getApplicationContext(), notesList);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(notesAdapter);
}

private void prepareData(){
    try {
        notesList = notesHandler.getAllNotes();
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("LOG", e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void writable(){
    notesHandler.getWritable(new Notes(
            subject.getText().toString(),
            text.getText().toString()));
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35147466/set-notifydatasetchanged-on-recyclerview-adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо добавить объект в адаптер и сделать notify, чтобы перерисовать recycler;

```
private void writable(){
    Notes notes = new Notes(subject.getText().toString(), text.getText().toString());
    ((NotesAdapter)recyclerView.getAdapter()).addNotes(notes);
}

////NotesAdapter.java
private List<Notes> notes;
...

public void addNotes(Notes newNotes) {
    notes.add(newNotes);
    notifyItemInserted(notes.size() - 1);
}
```